# How to render the component individually

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering, render

Hi i am new to the react , on the below code when i click the increment button , it run the loop and increment the count with 10. As of known if state changes it render the component ,  when i click increment button i able to see render message in console for only one time , for efficiency react collect all the changes and render only one time . but i don't want this , i need to see render message 10 times while clicking increment button. can you please help me on this.

```
import { Fragment, useReducer, useRef, useState,useMemo, useEffect } from "react"



export default function Sample()
{
   console.log("render")
   const [counter,setcount]=useState(0)
   const increment =()=>{
      for(let i=0;i<5;i++){
       setcount((prevcount)=>prevcount+1)
       setcount((prevcount)=>prevcount+1)
      }
   }
   return(
    <>
      <p>{counter}</p>
      <button onClick={increment}>increment</button>
   </>
   )
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this with `flushSync`. (https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/flushSync)
Something like this:

```js
  flushSync(() => {
         setcount((prevcount)=>prevcount+1)
      })
```